# Kubectl command failed: VS CODE - Plugin Kubernetes Extension Linux

Tags: linux, kubernetes, plugins, vscode-extensions, kubectl

In Vs-Code the plugin "KUBERNETES" shows the error (**Kubectl command failed**) when it tries to load the kubernetes that are loaded/running in my host (Linux - Ubuntu).

**Correction in VS-Code using Kubernetes extension**

1. (CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P)
2. Search for: `Open User Settings (JSON)`
3. click on `Preferences:` *`Open User Settings (JSON)`*
4. add    *`"vs-kubernetes.enable-snap-flag": true`* and save the file "***settings.json***"
5. [Capture of the solution when Kubernetes does not recognize the cluster in the host (Linux)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DiXW.png)

**I found the solution here**: https://github.com/vscode-kubernetes-tools/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues/522#issuecomment-645940091

Comment: If you've answered a question (even your own question), please explain the solution (not just a link a GitHub issue) in "Your Answer" (below) rather than by updating the question.